# Change where bootstrap "modal-open" class is assigned to instead of the body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Currently

```
modal-open
```

is assigned to the body when the modal is opened. How do i change where the class is added to instead of the body.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to change js that adds modal-open. It's a bit strange as behaviour, anyway you can do it softly or brutally.

Softly: intercept modal click for show and remove class to body adding to another element:

// Modal is first added to the body element and then removed and added to another element

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
  $('#myCustomElement').addClass('modal-open');
})
```

and then intercept also the close of the modal and add an execution of a second remove:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $('#myCustomElement').removeClass('modal-open');
})
```

**Brutally method**, to avoid that modal-open it's unnecessary added to body element:
go in TwitterBootstrap directory > js
Open modal.js
Search for modal-open , you will find (on version 3.2.0):

in

```
 Modal.prototype.show
```

you'll find

```
this.$body.addClass('modal-open')
```

in `Modal.prototype.hide`
you'll find

```
this.$body.removeClass('modal-open')
```

you have to change the target of `addClass` and `removeClass` and replace those instructions, if you have a fixed element it's enough simple (Ex: `$('#myFixedElement').addClass('modal-open')`, if it's a dynamic element it's complex and you'll have again to intercept Show function to add a `global var` in js to let `modal.js` know and read your target element. However you can also change the signature of those functions but i don't really suggest you to do that, basically you'll make your code too hard to maintain.

Comment: Just another one, the <div class="modal-backdrop"></div> that gets added when the modal is activated, is there a way to determine where that gets placed, as it stands it gets placed just before the closing body tag. I want to place it inbetween a <div id="sb-site"></div> Thankyou for all your help.

Comment: Ah i found, just change the append body bit to like the example you placed above thanks!

Comment: This is the default jquery behaviour, however if you care about this position (it's quite usless to change except if you are working in an iframe with a fixed size) you can just display:none in css while the modal it's not active, it's a bit tricky so eventually open another question. If you want to change you can do it brutally (in Modal.prototype.backdrop of modal.js you have to change this.$backdrop = $('<div class="modal-backdrop ' + animate + '" />')
        .appendTo($('#sb-site')) or copy, cancel, clone via jquery with same technique in first reply. Don't forget to vote ;)

Comment: I cant vote sorry dont have enough rep :(

Comment: I'm surprised that nobody noticed the missing '' for the body element. So the body should be $('body') and not $(body) .

Comment: You are wellcome :)

Comment: Anytime :) .Good method bro, but I noticed that there's a visible delay, meaning that it will first wait for the modal-open class to be added and then will fire your code. Any possible way to fire the class in the same time ?

Comment: I found the solution. So to avoid the delay, we should use 'show.bs.modal' and not 'shown.bs.modal' .Peace.